# PHP configuration OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, plesk

I have a problem in PHP configuration. I have Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and Plesk 9.5 Control Panel. I have a site for which I activated the openssl extension in php.ini but I faced this problem.

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error
occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how about looking in the error log?

Comment: It's usual here to describe what you've tried to do to solve it - have you done a web search for "windows server php ssl internal server error" yet? `:)`. Also, logs, as @qeek says.